# Why GeoServer is blocked during restarting when its GWC had seeded a large quantity of cahce file(PNG)

Tags: geoserver

There are a large quantity of layers have been published in our GeoServer, considering the performance, we have seeded the cache PNG files for these layers using GWC, but right now we restart GeoServer, it is always blocked at the moment of code '[storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - *** Found Java Environment GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR set to PATH , using it as the default profix'.

I am not sure if this is blocked or that It needs a long time to take to complete some tasks during restarting.

Comment: Actually, will it take you a long time to restart since there are many data to process.

Comment: Restarting can take a few minutes, and in that time any requests being sent to the GeoServer will be refused. We have over 600 layers in our GeoServer and that restart can take up to and over a minute.

Comment: That last log message is emitted by GWC starting up... you may want to ask the same question on the GWC mailing list.